# How to have an array of arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I'm new to python, but I'm solid in coding in vb.net. I'm trying to hold numerical values in a jagged array; to do this in vb.net I would do the following:

```
Dim jag(3)() as double
For I = 0 to 3
   Redim jag(i)(length of this row)
End
```

Now, I know python doesn't use explicit declarations like this (maybe it can, but I don't know how!). I have tried something like this;

> a(0) = someOtherArray

But that doesn't work - I get the error *Can't assign to function call*. Any advice on a smoother way to do this? I'd prefer to stay away from using a 2D matrix as the different elements of a (ie. a(0), a(1),...) are different lengths.

Comment: `a(0) = someOtherArray` is trying to call a function called `a` and pass in `0` as an argument. The correct syntax would be `a[0] = someOtherArray`.

Comment: That is a carry over from vb.net! I need to unlearn so much! Thank you. I am now getting an error "Name 'a' is not defined"

Comment: `arr = [[]]` I'm not sure what you're trying to do, python lists is dynamically assigned, but if you want a predefined length and dimension use list comprehensions.

Comment: That fixed It! Thank You!!

Comment: `a` is just the name of whatever you called your array and `[0]` is the index. You'll need to define an array first before assigning values to it.

Comment: `arr = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays):

> A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays. The elements of
>   a jagged array can be of different dimensions and sizes

Python documentation about [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html).

You could store a list inside another list or a dictionary that stores a list. Depending on how deep your arrays go, this might not be the best option.

```
numbersList = []

listofNumbers = [1,2,3]
secondListofNumbers = [4,5,6]

numbersList.append(listofNumbers)
numbersList.append(secondListofNumbers)

for number in numbersList:
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 4):

`arr = [[]]`

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, python lists is dynamically assigned, but if you want a predefined length and dimension use list comprehensions.

`arr = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]`